# How to interrupt an IO bound thread

Tags: .net, multithreading, streamreader, system.diagnostics

I am opening a System.Diagnostic.Process to read the stdout from a process and I would like to be able to interrupt it after a certain elapsed time.

```
try
{
    output = outputStream.ReadToEnd();
}
catch (ThreadInterruptedException e)
{
    return;
}
```

That doesn't work since the thread is in the ReadToEnd() method. I attempted to close the stream from the main thread, hoping that'd EOF the Read method, but that didn't work either.

Comment: Are you saying you want to specify some kind of timeout for `ReadToEnd` so you basically "read to end, or until 30 seconds have elapsed" or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard aborting

```
try 
{ 
    Timer watchdog = new Timer(abortMe, Thread.CurrentThread, timeout, Timeout.Infinite);
    output = outputStream.ReadToEnd(); 
    watchdog.Dispose();
} 
catch (ThreadAbortException e) 
{ 
    return; 
} 

private void abortMe(object state)
{
    ((Thread)state).Abort()
}
```

Actually I succeed in closing the stream when I work with TCP and UDP sockets: it triggers a SocketException and the thread gets successfully interrupted.

By the way, should your stream be an **input** stream? You're not supposed to read an output stream...

Comment: whoops. Since I'm reading the standard out, I named it output. A watchdog is exactly what I have, but it doesn't work. 
`static void doExit(object o)
{
    foreach (object thread in threads)
    {
            ((Thread)thread).Abort();
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

You could try calling `Dispose()` on the `Process` object as well as on the stream.  I imagine `outputStream` is linked to the `Process` instance via `Process.StandardOutput` so this ought to have the desired effect.

EDIT - see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055810/c-read-on-subprocess-stdout-blocks-until-another-subprocess-finishes/4055898#4055898) - this area of .Net I/O is prone to deadlocking, prefer async I/O if that is an option.